# Python wav plot, the graph is not plotting

Tags: python, audio, matplotlib, plot

I am making simple python audio player, but i have problem with plotting my wav file.

I use matplotlib and wave

code snippet:

```
spf = wave.open('music.wav','r')

signal = spf.readframes(-1)
signal = np.fromstring(signal, dtype=int, sep=' ')
fs = spf.getframerate()

Time=np.linspace(0, len(signal)/fs, num=len(signal))

plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Signal Wave...')
plt.plot(Time,signal)
plt.show()
```

program works but graph is not plotted, I think the problem might be in np.fromstring, but I am not quite shure.

This is my output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import wave

spf = wave.open('music.wav','r')

signal = spf.readframes(-1)
signal = np.fromstring(signal, 'Int8')

plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Signal Wave...')
plt.plot(signal)
plt.show()
```

with time axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import wave

spf = wave.open('music.wav','r')

signal = spf.readframes(-1)
signal = np.fromstring(signal, 'Int8')
fs = spf.getframerate()

Time=np.linspace(0, len(signal)/fs, num=len(signal))


plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Signal Wave...')
plt.plot(Time,signal)
plt.show()
```

Comment: it doesn't work, now i get value error. signal = np.fromstring(signal, 'Int16')
ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size

Comment: Ok, maybe your file is corrupted or its size is a multiple of 8 and not 16, the best thing you can do is to upload a sample file so we can see this together.

Comment: i use simple wav file from wavsource, here is the [link](http://www.filedropper.com/pulpfiction)

Comment: Ok the size was a multiple of 8, you get a plot by changing Int16 to Int8, I don't know if this is what you were looking but this is a start.